# Symfony2 Choicelist containing services (retrieved by tag)

Tags: php, symfony

I like to create a ChoiceList which contains all commands with a specific (custom) tag. I did read the compilerpass docs at the Symfony website but I don't have any idea how this can be accomplished. Someone can help?

Thx

Comment: You mean make a choicelist into a service?

Comment: I already solved it by creating a service chain for the tagging services and a choicelist service where I inject the service chain. This service chain contains a getClasses method an so I can build my choicelist dynamically.

Comment: You should probably answer your own question then. That way others time isn't wasted when they dig up your question to answer it :)

Comment: I'll do when I find some time